# TCP sockets unable to send messages in a burst

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp

Hi I have multiple systems communicating via message using TCP connections.

My send function looks like the following

```
def _send(self, message, dest):

    self.sendLock.acquire()
    message = pickle.dumps(message)
    #sending length
    message_length = len(message)
    self.outChan[dest].send('<MESSAGELENGTH>%s</MESSAGELENGTH>'
                            % str(message_length))

    for message_i in range(0, message_length, 1024):
        self.outChan[dest].send(message[:1024])
        message = message[1024:]

    self.sendLock.release()
```

And the receive thread looks like this:

```
def readlines(self, sock):

    while True:

        msg = ''

        opTag = '<MESSAGELENGTH>'
        clTag = '</MESSAGELENGTH>'

        while not all(tag in msg for tag in (opTag, clTag)):
            msg = sock.recv(1024)

        msglen = int(msg.split(clTag)[0].split(opTag)[1])
        msg = msg.split(clTag)[1]

        while len(msg) < msglen:
            msg += sock.recv(msglen-len(msg))

        self.rec.put(pickle.loads(msg))
```

After the message is read from self.rec a confirmation message is sent to the sender.

I have implemented my own buffer to control the traffic in the network. At any moment I would have sent atmost MAX_BUFFER_SIZE messages with no confirmation received.

Here is the problem: When program starts, it sends MAX_BUFFER_SIZE messages without waiting for the confirmation. But only a few of these MAX_BUFFER_SIZE messages are received.

In one of the simulations with MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 5, total 100 messages were sent and m2,m3 and m4 were not received. All other messages were received (in the order they were sent).

I doubt the error is in the initial sending burst, but I am unable to figure out the exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in the receive thread:

1. While inspecting the received message for the opening and closing tags, you are not appending to the already received part, but overwriting it.
2. After detecting the message length, you are losing the subsequent messages, that have their closing tag already received, but not analyzed yet.
3. You are possibly putting several messages together into `self.rec`.

Here is a corrected form, with comments explaining the changes:

```
def readlines(self, sock):

    msg = '' # initialize outside since otherwise remiander of previous message would be lost

    opTag = '<MESSAGELENGTH>' # no need to repeat this in each iteration
    clTag = '</MESSAGELENGTH>' # no need to repeat this in each iteration

    while True:

        while not all(tag in msg for tag in (opTag, clTag)):
            msg += sock.recv(1024) # += rather than =

        msglen = int(msg.split(clTag)[0].split(opTag)[1])
        msg = msg.split(clTag, 1)[1] # split just once, starting from the left

        while len(msg) < msglen:
            msg += sock.recv(msglen-len(msg))

        self.rec.put(pickle.loads(msg[:maglen])) # handle just one message
        msg = msg[msglen:] # prepare for handling future messages
```